# Ubuntu 17.04 freezing completely at random intervals

Tags: drivers, 17.04

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 instance that randomly locks up. Nothing responds so I have to turn off the PC using the power button.

I've realised that the issue starts when I try to reboot my computer... Sometimes the wifi stops working for like 15 seconds and then asks me for the wifi password.

[image]

Comment: Could be almost anything. Identify your hardware and check your logs . See https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: Need more info. What make/model computer? Show me `sudo lshw -C cpu` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Edit that output into your question, not the comments, please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: im new in this blog. how can i ping you?

Comment: @B.Amine You can ping users with `@`, e.g., `@EliahKagan` pings me. See the "What happens when I comment?" section of [this page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment) for details. See also [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) The information you've added is helpful but [please provide it as text instead of a screenshot](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713). You can copy text from the terminal to the clipboard, **[edit]** your post to paste it in, then select the pasted text and press Ctrl+K (or click the **{}** button) to format it properly. Thanks!

Comment: @B.Amine I've looked at your info. It mostly looks ok, but fstab looks a little strange. Did you manually partition your disk drive, or let Ubuntu handle it during the install? Show me `sudo fdisk -l`. The wi-fi issue might be a separate issue from the freezing. If after booting, you disconnect the wi-fi, and then reconnect, does it also ask for your password again? Also, please see my answer, below...

Comment: @heynnema i did manually partition my daisk drive during the install with a 2 ext4 partitions(one for / and the other for /home) and a swap partition

Comment: @B.Amine I see one EXT4 / root partition, and a swapfile (not a partition). I'm missing /home either on the disk, or in /etc/fstab.

Comment: @heynnema , maybe if i reinstall linux it will fix this issue?

Comment: @B.Amine couldn't hurt. Backup any important stuff, then do a complete "erase and install" (this will wipe the disk). If you don't have a specific reason to create a separate /home, then don't. Just use the default that Ubuntu lays down.

Comment: @heynnema okay i will do this, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you have `intel-microcode` installed...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Go to `www.memtest86.org` and download the free memory test and run it at least one complete pass... more if you have the time. If it freezes during the test, then you have a hardware problem. ie: bad memory, or something else.

**Update #1:**

Do you have an encrypted swap?

Comment: i have a simple swap

Comment: Did you run `memtest`?

Comment: im gonna reinstall the os and see if the problem persist, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Complete freeze can mean only 1 thing: *any* of all the drivers got stuck. This may be a faulty hardware or a faulty driver.

In practice, the first offender is an exotic hardware.

The second is faulty RAM. Use memtest to check it.

Then, Try removing all PC components that you can temporarily live without, like sound card or whatever.

Next candidate is a video card, because it is a most complicated piece of PC. If you have a CPU video card, or and old video card, try switching to it to see if the problem goes.